# When I try to draw my Pygame sprite, it crashes the game (AttributeError: 'Character' object has no attribute 'image')

Tags: python, pygame

When I try drawing the pygame sprite to the screen it crashes

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1500,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Screen")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface(100,200)
        self.image.fill = ("Red")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

character = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
character.add(Character())

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    character.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I tried to look up the answers on stack overflow but all the similar questions I looked at were answered in ways that didn't apply to me and looking at the functional parts of their code and no matter what I try I keep getting this error message.

AttributeError: 'Character' object has no attribute 'image'

Comment: The name of the constructor must be `__init__`, but not `_init_`

Answer (score -1):

Python errors are not always exact. Your code here: `self.image.fill = ("Red")` should be `self.image.fill(red)`.